# How to get wallet public and private key by passing mnemonic and password in node js

Tags: web3js, wallets, polygon, bip39

How to get public and private key of wallet by password and mnemonic in NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `fromMnemonic` in ethers.js. The next code snippet is from the [docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v4/api-wallet.html#wallet):

```js
let mnemonic = "radar blur cabbage chef fix engine embark joy scheme fiction master release";
let mnemonicWallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
```

Then you can access the address and the private key with:

```js
mnemonicWallet.address // "0x..."
mnemonicWallet.privateKey // "0x..."
```

As I said, it´s all in the [docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v4/api-wallet.html#wallet)